# How can I set up AWS CLI using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab

The idea is to create a scheduled task to run once per while and scan all S3 buckets to retrieve the list of objects with their size. I wrote a bash script, which works fine. However, I am thinking of create pipline in GitLab with terraform that will:

```
 1. launch EC2
 2. configure AWS cli
 3. copy .sh files from S3
 4. run the scripts and output will save into files on S3
 5. destroy EC2 to avoid costs
```

With the above approach, I can see one difficulty, I can not find useful information on internet.

How can I set up AWS CLI (aws configure and passing keys) on EC2 to execute AWS APIs using Terraform in secure way .?

I am expecting to set up AWS CLI on EC2 uisng terraform.

I searched for any community material such blogs explaining the process, for example: https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-secrets. However, still not sure if, for example, I will be able to use SSM to configure CLI on EC2 by terraform.

I am really appreciate for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign an [IAM Instance Profile](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile) to the EC2 instance with the necessary permissions instead of trying to pass in keys. When you run the AWS CLI tool inside the EC2 instance, it will automatically pick up and use the credentials from the instance profile.

You shouldn't need to run `aws configure` at all. All the `aws configure` command does is walk you through the steps of creating the `~/.aws/credentials` file. You are not required to have a `~/.aws/credentials` file to use the AWS CLI tool, it is just [one of many ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) to configure the AWS CLI tool.

Comment: Thank you, just right now I have manually create credential files with keys, to check if still I will have to execute aws configure. Works fine